# Как в Symfony2 в форме вывести список select из базы данных?

Tags: php, sql, symfony2, twig

У меня есть форма для заполнения данных в таблицу и я хочу с помощью тега select вывести данные в форму.
Для создания формы в контроллере я использую:

```
 ->add('id_server', 'choice', array(
            'label' => 'Выберите ваш сервер',
            'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default'),
            'choices'  => array('1' => '1', '2' => '1'),
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

Делаю выборку по таблице:

```
 $ems_select = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $dql_select="SELECT s FROM M4MinecraftBundle:Mc_server s WHERE s.id_user IN (:id_user)";
    $query_select = $ems_select->createQuery($dql_select)
        ->setParameters(array(
            'id_user' => $id_user,
        ));
    $qq=$query_select->getResult();
```

При данной выборке я получаю массив с двумя переменными. 
У меня такой вопрос, как этот массив поместить в 'choices'?
И при выборе отображалось название, а в value передавался id.

Пробовал кидать массив целиком, такой вариант не проходит. Так же не проходит по одному id кидать и по $qq[][].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;


->add('id_server', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Выберите ваш сервер',
        'attr' => array('class' => 'browser-default'),
        'required' => false,
        'class'  => 'M4MinecraftBundle:Mc_server',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $em) use($id_user){
             return $em->createQueryBuilder('s')
                 ->where('s.id_user IN (:id_user)')
                 ->setParameter('id_user', $id_user)
        }
))
```

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class M4\MinecraftBundle\Entity\Mc_server could not be converted to string
Нашел два ответа:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369022/symfony2catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-could-not-be-converted-to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570033/errorexception-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-could-not-be-converted-to?answertab=oldest#tab-top
Но их применение приводит к проблемам с доступом.

Comment: В классе :Mc_server надо определить метод __toString

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь работает. А я менял в вендоре.)

Comment: Можно добавить 'property' => 'name (title ??)' (сразу после 'query_builder' )

Comment: Но у меня еще один вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы выводило еще и 'name' в select?

Comment: Не надо в вендоре .........

Comment: в селект выводится toString или, если определено, property (если name, то должен быть метод getName() в классе, если nameAndId - должен быть определён метод getNameAndId())

Comment: Спасибо. Все заработало как надо)